# Socket operation on non-socket nginx error with Laravel php

Tags: php, macos, sockets, nginx

I'm simply trying to run php on nginx on my OSX.

### setup

my [php-fpm.conf](https://gist.github.com/abbood/a97b0e3fe3d45ad039ba6e14ea3a7799) file
my [www.conf](https://gist.github.com/abbood/ccaaf520331e9f5d312f79d956319aff) file
in my nginx.conf file I got this:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

### error

everytime I hit my server I get this error:

> 2017/12/31 01:45:25 [crit] 1102#0: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock failed (38: Socket operation on non-socket) while connecting to upstream, client: ::1, server: default, request: "POST /api/users/login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost:8000"

what do I do to fix this?

### update

I realized that inside my `php-fpm.d/www.conf` I got this line

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

so I updated my nginx conf file:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; 
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

but now I'm getting this error:

> 2017/12/31 02:07:24 [error] 1429#0: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: ::1, server: default, request: "POST /api/users/login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost:8000"

## update 3

from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/754378/203388) I added this to nginx conf:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; 
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

fastcgi.conf has this:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

but still same error message

Answer (score 0):

the solution was simple.. nginx was looking for my index.php.. I supplied the root of my laravel project when in fact I should have put the public diretory in laravel like so:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 8000 default_server;
        listen [::]:8000 default_server;
        server_name default;
        root /path/to/my/laravel/project/public/index.php;
```